# Transferring documents from Couchdb to Amazon S3

Tags: couchdb

I am looking to take all the documents from couchdb that are 90 days and older and send them to a Amazon S3 storage.  Does anyone know where I would start?  I already have a view in order to get all the ids of the couchdb docs that are 90 days and older.  I just don't know what to do from there?  There are millions of documents I want to transfer.  Thank you so much for any help you can give me.

Comment: Write code to loop through the documents of the view and store them however you want in S3 storage. I'm not sure where you're stuck?

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API